# iPhone UI small button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface

http://g.virbcdn.com/_f/cdn_images/resize_1280x640/29/PageImage-489404-2437983-IMG_4531.PNG
Hi all, we are trying to figure out how to do the small orange numbered label on the left in the image above. As you can see, when the number is 6, it looks like a circle. When it is 33, the label looks wider. Does anyone know how to make it?  Our developer believes it is made with UIButton. Is it possible to do it with label? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cornerRadius property of the CALayer class can be use to achieve this. Every view has a CALayer instance on which we can perform certain action. Means we can get rounded corners by using -

```
myLabel.layer.cornerRadius = //radius that we want;
```

Also for accessing layer we need to have following framework in our application-

```
<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: @RIP..Can we make the UILabel circular using corner radius?. The maximum value is 10 right?.

Comment: You need to set the cornerRadius = half the width of the view to make it a circle.

Comment: @deamonsarea - also there is no as such maximum value limitation.

Answer (score 1):

First Add QuartzCore FrameWork, then 
use in .m file

```
#import "QuartzCore/CALayer.h"
```

then use this code where do you want to show

```
UIButton *Mybutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];


    Mybutton.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
    [Mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [Mybutton setTitle:@"1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    Mybutton.frame = CGRectMake(135.0, 180.0, 40.0, 40.0);

    Mybutton.clipsToBounds = YES;

    Mybutton.layer.cornerRadius = 20;

    Mybutton.layer.borderColor=[UIColor greenColor].CGColor;

    Mybutton.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;

    [self.view addSubview:Mybutton];
```

button will look like...
[image: this]